# What data type should i use when i know the answer could be negative

Tags: c++, types

I'm currently working on a program to return a jumbled image to their original state. To do this I'm using the Sum of Squared differences algorithm. 
Due to the nature of this algorithm it's possible that the differences between two pixels could be negative, what data should i be using to correctly hold a negative value?

I'm currently using a double but I often find that the resulting "score" that was calculated was a "out of bounds number" - by this i mean one with letters - I know that the error is occurring at this location.

Many thanks

Comment: Doubles can hold negative values. What do you mean by 'one with letters'? Do you mean the number is being represented in hexadecimal (formatted like 0xBEEF) or in scientific notation (formatted like -2.5e15)? Or something else?

Comment: The integer data types char, short, long and int can be either signed or unsigned depending on the range of numbers needed to be represented. Signed types can represent both positive and negative values, whereas unsigned types can only represent positive values (and zero). This can be specified by using either the specifier signed or the specifier unsigned before the type name.

Comment: You have an error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the code? Also, what Eric Finn says is correct. Double is able to hold neagtive values, so this should work for you.